# Using make to move .o files to a separate directory

Tags: c++, object, compilation, makefile

I've tried numerous attempts to move my `.o` files to my `obj` folder, but no matter what I do, it simply just doesn't work.

Judging from the makefile provided, what is the best method to move `.o` files to a specified folder?

```
BIN = bin/
OBJ = obj/
TARGET = opengl_03
DEPS = main.o  displayinit.o initializer.o algorithms.o matrix3f.o window.o vertex3.o
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g 
LIBS = -lglut -lGLEW -lGL 
INCLUDEPATH = -L/usr/include/ -L/usr/lib/ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

$(TARGET) : $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN)$(TARGET) $(DEPS) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) 

displayinit.o : displayinit.cpp displayinit.h
    $(CC) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) -c displayinit.cpp && mv displayinit.o $(OBJ)displayinit.o
initializer.o : initializer.cpp initializer.h
    $(CC) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) -c initializer.cpp $(OBJ)
algorithms.o : algorithms.cpp algorithms.h
    $(CC) -c algorithms.cpp $(OBJ)
matrix3f.o : matrix3f.cpp matrix3f.h
    $(CC) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH)  -c matrix3f.cpp $(OBJ)
vertex3.o : vertex3.cpp vertex3.h
    $(CC) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH)  -c vertex3.cpp $(OBJ)
window.o : window.cpp window.h
    $(CC) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) -c window.cpp $(OBJ)
main.o : main.cpp
    $(CC) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) -c main.cpp $(OBJ)
```

Comment: does adding `mv *.o obj/` as the last line in the first target not work?

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Post that as answer and I'll accept you.

Comment: Why not build the files into the `obj/` directory from the start?

Comment: Also, your makefile is 90% redundant. Are you interested in how to make it more manageable?

Comment: @Kos Yes, absolutely. I'm VERY new to makefiles. Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**To specify where the object is created use `-o`**

```
window.o : window.cpp window.h
    $(CC) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) -c window.cpp -o $(OBJ)/$@
```

---

Here is what you could do:

1. specify the directory where you want the object files to go

   ```
   OBJDIR    =   objdir
   ```
2. Create a list of object files that need to be compiled, from the list of all `.cpp` files by replacing `.cpp` with `.o` and add the prefix `$(OBJDIR)/` to it:

   ```
   OBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard *.cpp)))
   ```

   So your $(OBJ) will look like: `objdir/window.o objdir/main.o` and so on
3. Add a target to create the directory if it does not exist:

   ```
   $(OBJDIR):
       mkdir $(OBJDIR)
   ```
4. Make the directory target before you make your main target:

   ```
   all: $(OBJDIR) myapp
   ```
5. Rule to compile all the `.o` object files in `$(OBJDIR)` from `.cpp` files in the current directory:

   ```
   $(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
       $(GCC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
   ```

   This will result in something like:

   ```
   g++ -c main.cpp -o objdir/main.o
   ```
6. Your main target is unchanged:

   ```
   $(TARGET): $(OBJ)
       $(GCC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
   ```

   This will look like:

   ```
   g++  -o myapp objdir/window.o objdir/main.o
   ```
7. For completeness add `clean` target to cleanup objects:

   ```
   clean:
       @rm -f $(TARGET) $(wildcard *.o)
       @rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
   ```
8. And define `.PHONY` targets, e.g. these will be made even if directories or files with the same name exist:

   ```
   .PHONY: all clean
   ```

So it should look like:

```
OBJDIR    =   objdir
OBJ       =   $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(wildcard *.cpp)))
TARGET    =   my app

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(OBJDIR) $(TARGET)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(GCC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(GCC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ 

clean:
    @rm -f $(TARGET) $(wildcard *.o)
    @rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
```

And if you have files such as `main.cpp` and `a.cpp` this is what `make` would do:

```
> ls
Makefile a.cpp    main.cpp

> make
mkdir objdir
g++ -I. -c a.cpp -o objdir/a.o
g++ -I. -c main.cpp -o objdir/main.o
g++ -o myapp objdir/a.o objdir/main.o 

> ls
Makefile a.cpp    main.cpp objdir   myapp

> make clean
> ls
Makefile a.cpp    main.cpp
```

And if you want to read more details about any of the above have a look at [GNU make doc page](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

Comment: Nice! For completeness I'll remind that the above also needs the dependencies. If you don't introduce them, then do `make clean && make` after each rebuild so that you won't run into silent linking problems.

Comment: Dependencies are material for another post ... I have a solution for them too.

Answer (score 4):

In response to the comment, some more tips:

### 1) Remove some redundancy

This part is very repetitive:

```
displayinit.o : displayinit.cpp displayinit.h
    $(CC) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) -c displayinit.cpp && mv displayinit.o $(OBJ)displayinit.o
initializer.o : initializer.cpp initializer.h
    $(CC) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) -c initializer.cpp $(OBJ)
algorithms.o : algorithms.cpp algorithms.h
    $(CC) -c algorithms.cpp $(OBJ)
# ...
```

You can replace it by two parts:

1) a more general rule, something like:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) $< -o $@
```

`$<` and `$@` are *automatic variables*, `$@` expands to the name of currently built target and `$<` is the first dependency (`$^` would be "all the dependencies", there are more such vars - see the [Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)).

2) any additional deps (i.e. headers):

```
displayinit.o: displayinit.h
matrix3f.o: matrix3f.h
main.o: main.h window.h displayinit.h

#etc
```

Note: For each `.o` file, its dependencies should contain:

- the `.cpp` from which it is built (the dependency is from the general rule),
- all `.h` files which are included from that `.cpp` files (which you need to add later).

Note that you omitted the latter part in your original makefile. This would cause you some problems one day.

### 2) Generate the deps automatically

Basically every time you add an `#include` in any of your files, you'd need to modify your makefile to reflect the new dependency between `.cpp`/`.o` and `.h` files. This is very troublesome, but fortunately there are automated solutions for that. There are two approaches for C/C++ here:

- Use your compiler to generate the dependencies for you (`gcc`/`g++ -MM` for instance).
- Use an additional tool such as `makedepend`.

Either way, you need to include that set of dependencies dynamically in the makefile. This needs some trickery, but once you have it, you never have to worry about dependencies. Have a google for "C++ makefile dependencies", there should be plenty of resources.

---

[Here's](http://www.jfranken.de/homepages/johannes/vortraege/make_inhalt.en.html) a to-the-point doc about Make.

Comment: +1. I really appreciate the advice. This will help very much.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me :

```
g++ test.cpp -c -o obj/test.o
```

So in your case, for example, you would make the following modification :

```
displayinit.o : displayinit.cpp displayinit.h
    $(CC) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) -c displayinit.cpp -o displayinit.o $(OBJ)displayinit.o
```

Also, for the final compilation, you need to pick up the .o files from the obj folder, so modify `DEPS` to have `bin/<xyz>.o`. Alternatively, you could `cd obj` before the final build :

```
$(TARGET) : $(DEPS)
    cd $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o ../$(BIN)$(TARGET) $(DEPS) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first target, add the command to move the files to the desired dir.

```
$(TARGET) : $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN)$(TARGET) $(DEPS) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDEPATH) 
    mv *.o obj/
```